# Test method that uses SessionStorage length

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a pagination method that uses the sessionStorage length to call one function or another.

Below is the part of the code I need to test:

Note: Uses table with angular material pagination;

```
 pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.currentPage = event.pageIndex;
    if (sessionStorage.length === 0 || sessionStorage.length === 1) {
      this.loadDados1(this.search.toLocaleLowerCase(), this.pageSize, this.currentPage + 1);
    } else {
      const dado = sessionStorage.getItem('contrato');
      const dados = JSON.parse(dado as string);
      this.loadDados2(this.search.toLocaleLowerCase(), this.pageSize, this.currentPage + 1, dados.contrato, dados.fornecedor);
    }
  }
```

Among some forms of tests that I have already done and redone, here is an example of the last implementation I tried.

```
 it('Should call method loadData1', () => {

    sessionStorage.setItem('retornoTela', 'view');
    const event = new PageEvent();
    event.pageSize = 10;
    event.pageIndex = 0;

    const search = 'test';
    const pageSize = event.pageSize;
    const currentPage = event.pageIndex;
    const loadDataSpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'loadData');

    component.pageChanged(event);
    expect(loadDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(search.toLocaleLowerCase(), pageSize, currentPage + 1);

  });
```

However, I always get the error below:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'contrato' of null

      109 |       const dado = sessionStorage.getItem('contrato');
      110 |       const dados = JSON.parse(dado as string);
    > 111 |       this.loadDados2(this.search.toLocaleLowerCase(), this.pageSize, this.currentPage + 1, dados.contrato, dados.fornecedor);
          |                                                                                                       ^
      112 |     }
      113 |   }
```

So, I'm trying to test the IF first, but it keeps dropping in ELSE, and I gave a console.log after doing the setItem in the sessionStorage, and the value comes back right, however, if I also do a console.log in the essionStorage.length, the return comes undefined.

I think it's precisely giving this error, because the sessionStorage is not equal to zero or one, and with that it keeps falling in the ELSE.